# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Instead of three @Formulas I want to create one that would fill my fake object with properties. MySimpleData is simpler version of MyHugeObject that I dont want to load fully.

```
 @Formula("(select myObject.id1 as id1, myObject.id2 as id2, myObject"
            + ".id3 as id3 from my_object myObject where myObject.id = this_id)")
    private MySimpleData mySimpleData = new MySimpleData();
```

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
>   mypackage.MySimpleData

```
 public class MySimpleData {

    private Long id1;
    private String id2;
    private String id3;

    public MySimpleData(Long id1, String id2, String id3) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
        this.id3 = id3;
    }

    public MySimpleData() {
    }  
}
```

Comment: Have you consider using  [projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) instead - looks like this is what you need from the example provided? `@Formula` could have unwanted performance impact - see hint #4 in this [article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/6-hibernate-mappings-you-should-avoid-for-high-performance-applications/)

Comment: Did you omit the package command to simplify the code example? Or is it maybe missing in your code?

Comment: where is the _id

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
@Formula("(select new MySimpleData(myObject.id1, myObject.id2, myObject.id3) from my_object myObject where myObject.id = this_id)")
private MySimpleData mySimpleData;
```

If you still get the same error, then add the full classpath in front of the `MySimpleData`.

like that `select new full.classPath.MySimpleData(..`